# USB flashdrive dynamic installation

Tags: live-usb

How can I enable ongoing changes to a working USB flash drive installation of Ubuntu 12? I would like to be able to add applications/tools and be able to use them on subsequent boot ups to the flash drive.

Comment: Please make your question more clear. Are you interested to install new software on your USB installation?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the way you created the USB flashdrive. If you used "Startup disk creator" it gives you the option to store the changes "in reserved extra space".

So:

- get a USB stick that is big enough to store your changes,
- then use "Startup disk creator" 
  [image]
- load the Ubuntu ISO file that you downloaded from the Ubuntu site
- the use the slider on the bottom of the window to allocate  space of the USB stick for storing settings
  [image: Make startup Disk]
- next time you boot with the USB stick, the changes and installations will remain there, provided that there is enough space